# 14.04 - GPG error, public key not available

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

apt-get update returns:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D46F45428842CE5E
```

i've tried:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D46F45428842CE5E
```

also tried the fix for [bug 1263540](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1263540), all without success.

fairly new to ubuntu too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found this server for this key but unfortunately seems down.

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys D46F45428842CE5E
```

At least try this:
[Try to import all missing GPG keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey#answer-386003)

Comment: when trying to add the webupd8 repository i get this error:  'gpg: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: UP'

Comment: Try ON YOUR OWN! :  `mkdir temp` then use `sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libreadline* temp`. Now  `sudo ldconfig` and finally `sudo apt-get update`.  Use this with care and if something goes wrong please post new question.

Comment: Thanks for that, though still getting original error.